# Difference between Sagemaker notebook instance and Training job submission

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, amazon-sagemaker

I am getting an error with a Sagemaker training job with the error message "OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum". This is an image identification problem with code written in keras and tensorflow. The input for this is a large npy file stored in an s3 bucket.
The code works fine when run the Sagemaker notebook cells but errors out when submitted as a Training job using boto3 request.
I am using the same role in both places. what could be the cause for this error? I am using ml.g4dn.16xlarge instance in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I would check is

1. Framework Versions used in your notebook instance vs the training job
2. Instance Storage volume for the training job, since you are using G4dn it comes with attached SSD which ideally should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug, Requests and urllib3 should only ask for a maximum number of bytes and it is capable of handling at once.